# How to update chart.js chart with new data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, chart.js

Hi I have a chart in chart.js here is the code:

```
let myChart = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
let newChart = new Chart(myChart, {
type: 'line',
data: {
    labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7' ],
    datasets: [{
    data: [
        7.9,
        8.2,
        6.4,
        9.8,
        6.7,
        8.1,
        9.2
    ],
    fill: false,
    label: 'Time to complete'
    }

    ]
},
options: {
    title:{
    display: true,
    text: 'Time taken per sample'
    }
}
});
```

This displays fine in my browser.

I want to update the data dynamically upon a button press,

I have already setup this functionality so that when my button is pressed I send a request for the new data and get this back in JSON form that looks like `{data: [...]}`.

My question is how can I write the code update the chart with the new info?

Here is what I have:

```
$(".newData").click(function() {

      request = $.ajax({
              url: '/update_data',
              type: "POST"
            });

       request.done(function(data){
            // Need to update chart here!
       });
  });
```

I tried `$('myChart').data=data`

But alas it did not work!

I think it is probably a one-liner but I can't figure it out. There are other questions like this but they seem to be dealing with appending data and animating it rather completely new data.

Comment: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update dataset

```
  newChart.data.datasets[0].data=data//your data coming from  service
```

then

```
 newChart.update();
```